# Find the marginal density functions for X and Y.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

[image]

I know that to find the marginal density functions for X and Y, I need to integrate f(x,y) wrt y and x respectively. My problem here is that I don't know what f(x,y) is so can anyone give me some hints on how to find f(x,y)?

Comment: Isn't $f$ just constant on the indicated region?

Answer (score 2):

The problem states that $(X,Y)$ has a uniform distribution over the region

$$\Omega=\{(x,y)\ |\ 0\leq y\leq 1-x^2, -1\leq x\leq 1\}.$$

You know that the density $f(x,y)$ of a uniform distribution is constant, so it is equal to the constant $C$ that makes

$$\int_{\Omega} C \ dx\ dy = 1$$

true.

Comment: How do I find C?

Comment: For starters, just calculate the integral like you would do in a calculus course, where you think of $C$ as some given constant. The way you do it is by integrating twice, first with respect to $y$ and then with respect to $x$ (so the other way around compared to my notation). So you need to find $\int_{-1}^1\int_{0}^{1-x^2} C \ dy\ dx$.

Comment: Okay, got it! Thank you so much!! :)

Comment: @OinkOink no problem, glad I could help.